# Llave foranea en relación dependiente no almacena su valor en JPA (Java)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Tengo la siguiente relación  OneToOne bidireccional en JPA:
Tengo una entidad empleado que tiene como llave primaria el dni y como llave foránea el id de su usuario.A su vez,tengo del lado del usuario,un id llave primaria y como llave foránea,el id del empleado (dni).

**El owner de la relación es el empleado**.
Este no me da ningún problema,ya que se almacena correctamente la llave foránea del usuario,pero este ultimo,no me guarda el valor de la llave foránea correspondiente(dni del empleado).

Acá se puede ver como tengo implementado el código:

Clase Empleado:

```
    package com.example.demo.entity.empleados;

import com.example.demo.entity.Direccion;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.io.Serializable;

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="dni")
@Entity
@Table(name="empleados")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Empleado implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "pk_empleado_dni")
    private String dni ;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre ;

    @Column(name = "apellido")
    private String apellido ;

    @Column(name = "correo_electronico")
    private String correoElectronico ;

    @Column(name = "edad")
    private byte edad ;

    @Column(name = "horas_dias")
    private byte horasDia ;

    @Column(name = "salario")
    private float salario ;

    //@Column(name = "fk_cargo")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_cargo")
    private Cargo cargo ;
    //@Column(name = "fk_area")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_area")
    private Area area ;
   // @Column(name = "fk_direccion")
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_direccion")
    private Direccion direccion ;



    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_usuario",referencedColumnName = "pk_usuario")
    private Usuario usuario ;
}
```

Clase Usuario:

```
    package com.example.demo.entity.empleados;

import com.example.demo.entity.empleados.Empleado;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

import java.io.Serializable;

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "pk_usuario")
private int id ;

@Column(name = "correo")
private String correo ;

@Column(name = "contrasenia")
private String contrasenia ;

//@JoinColumn(name = "fk_empleado")
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "usuario",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Empleado empleado ;
}
```

Acá se puede ver como se guardan correctamente los datos del lado del empleado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente imagen se puede ver como el usuario no almacena el dni del empleado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro que es lo que estoy haciendo mal,traté de hacer algo parecido a esto:

```
 empleado.getUsuario().setEmpleado(empleado);
```

para luego llamar a la función que se encarga de guardar la información en JPA ,pero sin éxito.

Comment: Buenas noches Marce.Muchas gracias por la recomendación,acabo de editar la publicación y agregué el codigo

Comment: Grande maestro!!!